# Xpath not working on xml with default namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am a calling a soap service, which is returning following response:

**Original Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns="http://example2.com/ResultMain"
xmlns:ResponseResult="http://example.com/Result" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Response>
         <result>
            <ResponseResult:errorCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ResponseResult:isSuccess>true</ResponseResult:isSuccess>
            <ResponseResult:message>No Data found</ResponseResult:message>
         </result>
      </Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to derive the value of "message" element from the result, but no matter which xpath i am using, it is not working and i am getting following error. I am trying it on an online [editor](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

**Error:**

```
The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'http://example2.com/ResultMain'.
```

**Sample Xpath that I used:**

```
//*[local-name()='message']
```

But If I modified the service response and removed the default namespace, it is working fine. etc.

**Modified Service Response:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 

xmlns:ResponseResult="http://example.com/Result" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Response>
         <result>
            <ResponseResult:errorCode xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ResponseResult:isSuccess>true</ResponseResult:isSuccess>
            <ResponseResult:message>No Data found</ResponseResult:message>
         </result>
      </Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So can anybody please help me solve the problem that how can I bypass or somehow ignore the default namespace.

Comment: which editor/language you are usign

Comment: I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and It provides XPath support. I have also tried this on multiple XPath online tester/editor tools. It haven't worked anywhere.

Comment: i tried in my editor it is working fine

Comment: which one? Can you make it work in any online editor?

Comment: i tired here http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester with this one //ResponseResult:message it worked. for some reason this //*[local-name()='message'] is not working in online editor

Comment: this is working in online editor //*[local-name() = 'ResponseResult:message']

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html is broken in my view, your path `//*[local-name()='message']` is fine.

Comment: it worked //*[local-name() = 'message']

Comment: Thanks guys, It worked, it was very stupid of me to use the same website again and again for testing purposes. That website is broken.

Comment: xsltransform.net is probably the best, but it occasionally is unavailable.